# How to show q[1-4] for month quater in range bar chart in x-axis in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2012

I have created a range bar chart in ssrs. I want to show  x-axis label in quater format i.e q1 for jan,q2 for apr,q3 for july,q4 for oct

Here is the screenshot. I need to change from Month Jan-Q1.

[image: screenshot2]

[image: screenshot3]

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about your dataset fields so I am guessing.

Try this expression in x-axis labels:

```
=Switch(
Fields!Month.Value="Jan","Q1",
Fields!Month.Value="Apr","Q2",
Fields!Month.Value="Jul","Q3",
Fields!Month.Value="Oct","Q4"
)
```

**EDIT:** Add expression to label x-axis in range chart.

1. Right click on Category Groups Collection (in my case Month)

[image]

2. In general tab go to label textbox and add the expression.

[image]

3. Input the expression I provided you. (In my case Month is the calendar number of year, you should use the above expression)

[image]

4. This is the preview.

[image]

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: Just a quick question.. Where I should write this expression ? I have already tried on "Label format" on X-axis but it does not works for me.

Comment: Please tell us how are you setting `Category Groups`, also a dataset example would be very useful.

Comment: Actually i am trying to build Activities & milestones report.So i am having the Project start & End date.X-axis is running from start to end date of project.Dataset is not having these auto generated values on X-axis .When we select on Axis of the report & go to properties we have tried using the switch case in "Label format" whatever you have mentioned.But we want to set value of this Label as Q1,Q2,etc & their is no property as such "label value" for Axis, if range bar chart is considered.

Comment: Yes exactly this is true in bar chart ,but we have range bar chart.In range bar chart we specify activity category in y-axis and in x-axis we specify the range of startscduled and end scheduld ,becoz it is a range bar chart

Comment: check I have uploaded my report screen shot

Comment: I mean the query results (data) you are using to populate the chart. At least can you provide a list of fields and description?. You can add `calculated field` to the dataset just right click the dataset in fields tab press `Add` and set the expression I provided in my answer, then use the calculated field (quarter) wherever you are using the month field.

Comment: check i have uploaded dataset result